# eslint Parsing error: Unexpected token function with async

Tags: node.js, eslint, eslintrc

I am getting the following error in async usage on ESLINT.

> eslint Parsing error: Unexpected token function with async

Here is my `eslintsrc`

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb-base",
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "off",
    "func-style":"error",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": false, "optionalDependencies": false, "peerDependencies": false, "packageDir": "./"}]
},
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion":8
 }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my async

```
const get = async function get(req, res) {
  const user = await service.get();
  console.log("From db",user.username);
  res.send('ok');
};
```

Comment: Can you please also share the use of `async` it's raising the error about?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski updated my async code

Comment: Not seeing the same error for the snippet, at least with [ESLint's demo](https://eslint.org/demo/). – Possibly a typo? You mention the settings are saved in `eslintsrc`. There shouldn't be a 2nd `s` in the file name.

Comment: Its a typo the  filename is `eslintrc` but still i am getting the same error from eslint

Comment: Just in case this is happening to people using `async/await` for the first time. This error also appears if you use `await` inside a function that is not defined as `async`. In which case it's not an EsLint configuration issue, but rather a syntax error.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I was getting this error also, I added the following to my eslintrc:

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },

  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8
  }
}
```

Comment: "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8
  }
works for me!

Comment: It works because you add the support for async

Comment: This doesn't work currently with similar file with `commonjs` `es6` `node` `mocha` tru in env
and parserOptions `requireConfigFile: false` `parser: "@babel/eslint-parser"` `"ecmaFeatures.ecmaVersion": 2018` and `"sourceType": "module"`

Comment: This did not resolve it for me. I am using the latest version of everything and still getting the error.

Comment: My .eslintrc file had ```"ecmaVersion": 6,```.  By changing the 6 to 8 it resolved my problem.

Comment: I actually believe you got the wrong eslint file name. Use `.eslintrc.js` for "normal" commonjs. Use `.eslintrc.mjs` is you are using ESM.

Answer (score 7):

In my case it got fixed when I just changed from:

> "parserOptions": {
>       "ecmaVersion": 8  }

to

> "parserOptions": {     "ecmaVersion": 2018 }

Comment: changed what ?.

Answer (score 2):

It's an error regarding `func-style`. By default it uses type `expression`, and the correct way to represent functions using this as `expression` is:

```
const get = async get(req, res) {
  const user = await service.get();
  console.log("From db",user.username);
  res.send('ok');
};
```

Check the docs for further examples, https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-style

UPDATE:
Forgot to see you have added error, what you were doing was right,

```
const get = async function get(req, res) {
  const user = await service.get();
  console.log("From db",user.username);
  res.send('ok');
};
```

Just remove `func-style` from eslint.

Comment: got another error [eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token get
[js] ',' expected.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check it once.

Comment: you are asking to remove func-style` from eslintrc rules??

Comment: Yes, remove it.

Comment: removed but still i got the error i am using airbnb style guide

Comment: I do not have any rules or recommended rules within my eslint file and no file supersedes my esline file and I still get that error. Does that mean this is activated within eslints core automatically?

Comment: `"rules": {"func-style": "off"}` did not work for me

Answer (score -6):

If you are new in the project I recommend just to go back with promises :)

```
function openTabs(array) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //... your code
    });
}
```

Comment: Bad answer. You shouldn't change something like this because of ESLINT, especially when it won't cause an exception when running it, this is just asking for a more tedious approach.