# VSCode ESLint extension giving error "Unexpected Token" for my javascript code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am using vscode with the ESLint extension.

I have node 16 installed and my eslint config is as follows...

```
{
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "overrides": [
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest"
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
}
```

I have the following javascript code...

```
async function func1 (val) {
  console.log(val);
}

await func1("blah");
```

The last line of code is giving the error...

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token func1
```

Why is this error occuring?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50285821/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token-function-with-async

Comment: This did not resolve, as my eslint options already have the latest parser version set.

Comment: At a guess, this is due to top level `await`. But that should be okay in the latest ESLint.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ESLint >= 8.0, in your config file, replace `"es2021"` with `"es2022"`:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es2022": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "overrides": [
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest"
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
}
```

The reason is that you are using top-level `await` syntax, which was finalized in ES2022: https://eslint.org/blog/2021/10/eslint-v8.0.0-released/#highlights.

Comment: My config file is clearly posted in the question and indicates I already have es2021 defined.

Comment: @Scorb That's the error. Please, re-read my answer.